# ROC surfaces in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, roc

If my response variable has 2 levels, 0 and 1, I can use a [ROC curve](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/) to assess the accuracy of my predictive model.  But what if my response variable has 3 levels, -1, 0, and 1?  Is there a way to plot "[ROC surfaces](http://users.dsic.upv.es/grupos/elp/cferri/vus-ecml03-camera-ready4.pdf)" in R?

I started trying to code this up myself, but I couldn't figure out how to calculate and plot the surface.

```
library(rpart)
library(randomForest)

y <- as.factor(c(-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,-1,0,1,0,1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,1,0))
x1 <- rnorm(1:30)
x2 <- rnorm(1:30)
x3 <- rnorm(1:30)

model <- randomForest(y~x1+x2+x3)
model
y1 <- predict(model,type='prob')

DF <- data.frame(y=as.numeric(as.character(y)),'negone'=y1[,'-1'],'zero'=y1[,'0'],'one'=y1[,'1'])

DF$FPrOne <- 
DF$FPrNegOne <- 
DF$TPR <- 

library(rgl)
plot3d(DF$FPrOne,DF$FPrNegOne,DF$TPR,type=1)
```

Comment: Why not just plot the three ROC curves for -1 vs. 0/1, 0 vs. -1/1, and 1 vs. -1/0?

Comment: I noticed you are predicting the train set -- this is wrong, since you'll get a too optimistic approximation. You should use OOB votes instead, which are in `model$votes`.

Comment: And well, this ROC surface is 5D in 6D space... not too feasible for `rgl` =]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some idea to stuff it into 2D in 3D is a surface defined by true positive rate of each class ([He, Xin, B.D. Gallas, and E.C. Frey. 2009.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5306177)), so I'll go this way.

Let's say the `g` variable holds the vote proportions:

```
g<-model$votes;
```

First you need two thresholds, one for each of some two classes (let's say for 1 and -1) -- I'll call them `qP` and `qN`, which will create the surface:

```
qP<-qN<-seq(0,1,30)
```

Now, let's calculate a true positive rate for positive class (and negative, which is mostly the same):

```
tpP<-function(qP,qN,g) sum(g[,"1"]>qP & y=="1")/sum(y=="1")
tpN<-function(qP,qN,g) sum(g[,"-1"]>qN & y=="-1")/sum(y=="-1")
```

The zero class gets the rest of votes:

```
tpZ<-function(qP,qN,g) sum(!(q[,"-1"]>qN) & !(q[,"1"]>qP) & y=="0")/sum(y=="0")
```

Now we just have to apply it over the whole qPxqN, easiest way is to use `outer` on `Vectorize`d functions (note that this is not the effective method, though I don't see any obvious optimizations which will not degenerate readability):

```
X<-outer(qP,qN,Vectorize(tpP,vec=c("qP","qN")),g)
   outer(qP,qN,Vectorize(tpN,vec=c("qP","qN")),g)->Y
Z<-outer(qP,qN,Vectorize(tpZ,vec=c("qP","qN")),g)
```

Now all points (`X[[i]]`,`Y[[i]]`,`Z[[i]]`) should lay on the surface; the matrix format is suitable to run `rgl.surface`:

```
rgl.surface(X,Z,Y) //Yup, the order is weired
```

[image]

Definitely does not seem too good, but this is what one can expect on a small random data ;-)